# replace a union query involving a left join

Tags: oracle

I have a left join and a Union .
I was thinking if it is possible to replace the union with a join

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col1,
from t1
left join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1)
union
select t3.col1,t3.col2,t2.col1
t2.col1,
from t3
left join t2 on (t3.col1 = t2.col1)
```

I am on Oracle 12c can this query be re-written without the union ?
I tried this but the results don't match the union query's results

```
    select t1.col1,t3.col2,t2.col1,
    from t1
    left join t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1)
    left join t3 on (t3.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col1 = t2.col1)
```

Any ideas is this even possible ?

Comment: No, it isn't. And since you are using `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`, and outer joins, it may not even be possible to re-write as `t1 left join (t2 union t3)` - you may get a different result. Questions - do you need `UNION` or should you actually use `UNION ALL`? Then - since you join on `col1`, do you really need both `t1.col1` and `t2.col1` in the `select` for the first join (and similarly for the second join)?

Comment: WHY do you want to avoid `UNION`? Is it for performance reasons? In that case think seriously about `UNION` vs `UNION ALL` - do you really need the former?

Comment: Hi The query performance well i was thinking from a readability perspective a join is more pleasant on the eye then a Union.And also the data model is awkward so i have to first construct the tables t1 and t3 to make this work

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of alternatives for you:

Do the union of t1 and t3 first, before joining to t2:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t2.col1
from   (select col1, col2
        from   t1
        union
        select col1, col2
        from   t3) t
       left outer join t2 on (t.col1 = t2.col1);
```

Use a full outer join of t1 and t3 first, before joining to t2:

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t2.col1
from   (select coalesce(t1.col1, t3.col1) col1,
               coalesce(t1.col2, t3.col2) col2
        from   t1
               full outer join t3 on t1.col1 = t3.col1
                                     and t1.col2 = t3.col2) t
       left outer join t2 on (t.col1 = t2.col1);
```

N.B. Both are untested, since you neglected to provide any sample data in any of the three tables. You'll have to test these approaches yourself.

ETA: Also, I believe both these approaches should work **for the example as given**. If your real world scenario differs from that in your question, it's possible neither approach will be of use.

ETA2: Given you're wishing to tweak your query for readability, I'd go with my first proposed solution (assuming it works for you, of course!), since the union deduplicates the rows from tables t1 and t3 *before* joining to t2 - that way, you're reducing the work needed to do the join. Also, the union has less to check too (2 cols instead of 3).

It may have a union in it, but it's sure as heck nicer to read than my second suggestion! At least, in my opinion *{;-)

Comment: Hi - I didn't check back till now. As you can see, I deleted my comment - I misread your query initially. Then I realized what it was doing, and I deleted my comment, I believe, before you finished your reply.  :-)